# Bundling TypeScript types from a local Yarn Workspace with Rollup

Tags: typescript, bundling-and-minification, rollup

I have a monorepo, created as a [Yarn Workspace](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces), which has an API and an SDK.

The API is the backend, and the SDK is a sugary library for interacting with said backend. The API is a private package while the SDK will be published and available to anybody. Both are written in TypeScript.

Naturally, the SDK and API have some cross-over when it comes to TypeScript types. As the API defines what it accepts in arguments to its' endpoints, it seems best to re-use these types in the SDK to define what the SDK needs to "send" to the API.

I can obviously export these types from the API, and import them in the SDK:

```js
// api/src/index.ts
export type EndpointArgumentType = {
  resourceId: string
  body: Record<string, unknown>
}
```

```js
// sdk/src/index.ts
import { EndpointArgumentType } from 'api'
```

However, when bundling the SDK with [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/), I'm having some difficulty making sure that the API types are bundled properly with the resulting SDK bundle. References to `EndpointArgumentType` are indeed present in the bundles `index.d.ts` file, but they require access to the API as an external dependency. The code is practically identical to that of the source code:

```
// sdk/lib/index.d.ts
import { EndpointArgumentType } from 'api';
```

This is no good, as the API will not be available publicly and therefore the lookup will fail when the library is being used outside of my workspace.

How am I able to bundle local dependency TypeScript types into a bundle? Obviously I don't want any of the business logic from the API (as this should not be public), I just need the types to be declared inline in my SDK bundle.

I have put together a very small [reproducible example](https://github.com/shennan/example-monorepo-api-type-bundling) as a Github repo, for anybody who wishes to have a play and attempt to make this work.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I'm struggling with the exact same issue.